# Increase capacity for vector

Tags: c++, vector, push-back, capacity

Disclaimer 1 - I'm new to programming
Disclaimer 2 - I have searched and searched, but can't find the help I'm looking for.

For a project, I am more or less re-writing the vector class in a more stripped down form. The part I'm hung up with is writing the push_back method. All's well until I have to increase the capacity of the array.

I assume what should be done is create a new vector with the increased size, and then copy the elements from the old vector to the new one, then use the assignment operator to assign oldVector to newVector.

I have either written my push_back method incorrectly, overloaded the = operator incorrectly, or else I'm just lacking in my understanding on what should be happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

When compiling, I get the error "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" on the line where I assign this = tempV

```
template <class T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator = (const Vector<T> & v)
{
    int newSize = v.size();
    int newCapacity = v.getCapacity();
    data = new T[newCapacity];
    for(int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
        data[i] = v.data[i];
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
void Vector <T> :: push_back(const T & number)
{
    if(numItems == capacity)
    {
        Vector <T> tempV(this->capacity * 2);
        for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
            tempV.data[i] = data[i];
        *this = tempV;
    }
    if(numItems < capacity)
        data[numItems++] = number;
}
```

**UPDATE**
So I see why my code wouldn't compile while using

```
*this = tempV;
```

in my copy method, I was using v.size and not v.size() as a method. After fixing that, the code compiles and runs, however the capacity of my vector is the same and did not increase as I was expecting. I'm still missing something. The code above has been updated.

Thanks again for any/all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have to create a new `Vector<T>`? Just create a new array:

```
template <class T>
void Vector <T> :: push_back(const T & number)
{
    if(numItems == capacity)
    {
        capacity *= 2;
        T* newData = new T[capacity];
        std::copy(data, data + numItems, newData);
        delete[] data;
        data = newData;
    }

    data[numItems++] = number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Databyte, this was the solution. I don't entirely understand, however, how the actual capacity is being copied. From what I understood, when you copy over an array like that, any unfilled memory doesn't get copied. If you have some extra time and wouldn't mine, I would like to understand how this works (again I'm new to programming)

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question... The vector is a Container that stores it's items in a continuous chunk of memory (to allow fast index-access). To achieve this the vector uses an internal array. To improve performance a larger array (as needed) is allocated (thats the capacity). The push_back new has one job: to add a new element at the end of the vector (see last line of push_back). But sometimes the internal array is already full. In this case we have to allocate new and larger continuous memory, copy the data into the new array and delete old array afterwards (line 4-11).